# C datatype : Between Short and Int

Tags: c, types, int, short

I read a book talking about C , it's better for me to present the code first and question in the latter.

#### First Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
short num = 3;

printf("%hd\n" , num );

return 0;

}
```

#### Second Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
short num = 3;

printf("%d\n" , num );

return 0;

}
```

*Special note*: I'm using intel based pc so int size is 32-bit.

**Question :**

1.) The book mention this two code could run correctly although one of it uses the `%hd` specifier while the other uses `%d` specifier.

2.)The reason from the book is that because C mechanism would automatically convert the type *short* to *int* for faster computation,that is why by using the `%d` specifier or even `%ld` which is 32-bit would yield the correct result too.

3.)My question is , when does this conversion occurred??Is it during the time we passed it as an argument to the `printf()` function , just like how float variable is converted to double when it is passed as an expression or an argument, or by the time we initialize the variable with a value `3`??

4.)Actually I've done a small experiment , that is by printing out the size of the variable num using the `sizeof` operator along with `printf()` function , and it shows me `2 bytes`.But i still not sure when the conversion happen.

5.)If the conversion occurred during the time we assigned the value to the short variable,what's the point of creating a short variable??(***This question should be ignore if it's not the case*)

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: "intel based pc" do not relate anything to int size. On old 16-bit x86 int would be 16 bit, and in x86_64, some compiler implementation will have int to be 64 bit. Intel Itanium also have 64-bit int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call a function without a prototype *or* a function with variable arguments, like printf(3), then C applies something called the *default argument promotions*.

These conversions promote float to double and anything smaller than `int` to `int` or `unsigned int`. This tends to harmonize most of the types.

This is an interesting feature that, possibly, C introduced to the world. It actually happens to some extent at the instruction set level or ABI level. Parameters are passed in registers or on the stack, and typically no one allows misaligning the stack or leaving junk in higher-order bits.

Just one more reason why C matches the hardware so well and runs so fast.

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes, `%d` and `%hd` are equivalent in this case.  `printf()` is a variadic function, so the rules say that "integer promotions" are applied to the arguments.  `printf()` doesn't see a `short` value at all, it just sees an `int`.
2. `%ld` is for `long int`.  This could be bigger in size than a plain `int`, so here the book is wrong.
3. The conversion occurs in the call to `printf()`.  Any `short int` passed to `printf()` is converted to `int` by the compiler.  The `short int` is not changed of course (not sure what that means anyway!)
4. When you print the size using `sizeof`, you are printing a number that is the size of the `short int` (and the number is of type `size_t`).  `printf()` doesn't even see the `short int`, `sizeof` operator does, and reports the correct size.
5. The point of creating a `short` variable is that if you want a `short` variable, you create one.  This is true for most variables of course :-).  But if you don't think you need a `short int` specifically, it's okay to just use `int`.

Answer (score 1):

This conversion happens in the call to `printf`, because for variadic functions, all the arguments passed in as part of the `...` get widened to `int` (or `double`, if the argument is a `float`) first.